# How to get enum value by parsing another enum with same named constants

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Consider the following two enumerations;

```
public enum EFileTag {
    Clean,
    Modified
}

public enum EHgFileTag {
    Modified = 'M',
    Clean = 'C'
}
```

with the value of EFileTag, I need to get the equivalent value of EHgFileTag
Example: **'C'** for **EFileTag.Clean**

I solved the problem by using;

```
EFileTag ft = EFileTag.Clean;
string ftstr = Enum.GetName (typeof (EFileTag), ft);
if (Enum.TryParse (ftstr, out EHgFileTag tag)) {
    char hgft = (char)tag;
}
```

Is there a better/efficient way to accomplish the conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a Dictionary like:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<EFileTag, EHgFileTag> dict = new Dictionary<EFileTag, EHgFileTag> 
{
    { EFileTag.Clean, EHgFileTag.Clean },
    { EFileTag.Modified, EHgFileTag.Modified }
}
```

Now you can efficiently get one enum by passing the other.

```
var tag = dict[EFileTag.Clean];
//tag would be EHgFileTag.Clean
//you can get the char now like you did in your example
var hgft = (char)tag;
//hgft would be 'C'
```

Edit:

I always thought that using enums this way didn't make much sense. As you now requested to add another enum to the mix, I decided to change the concept away from enums.

```
public enum EFileTag
{
    Clean,
    Modified
}

public class FileTag
{
    public EFileTag EFileTag { get; private set; }
    public char EHgFileTag { get; private set; }
    public char EGitFileTag { get; private set; }

    public FileTag(EFileTag eFileTag, char eHgFileTag, char eGitFileTag)
    {
        EFileTag = eFileTag;
        EHgFileTag = eHgFileTag;
        EGitFileTag = eGitFileTag;
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<EFileTag, FileTag> tags = new Dictionary<EFileTag, FileTag>
    {
        {EFileTag.Clean, new FileTag(EFileTag.Clean, 'C', ' ') },
        {EFileTag.Modified, new FileTag(EFileTag.Modified, 'M', 'M') },
    };

    var tag = tags[EFileTag.Clean];
    //tag would be of class FileTag
    var hgft = tag.EHgFileTag;
    //hgft would be 'C'
    var gft= tag.EGitFileTag;
    //gft would be ' '
}
```

Now you only have one enum describing your basic file tag and attached to it have the chars you want to access. This is much cleaner and better to understand and handle than having multiple enums. For the future I would recommend you don't use enums the way you did, as it's really not the way they are supposed to be used. Enums are a way to name an enumeration for understanding purposes only not a way to carry actual values.
Also if you want to add another char or something else you can now easily do it.

Comment: Consider a scenario with a third enum with same named constants

`public enum EGitFileTag {
    Modified = 'M',
    Clean = ' '
}`

What will now be an efficient solution for conversion, provided the given **EFileTag** value and we only get to know the type of repo **(.git,.hg,...etc)** dynamically on the fly? Can you give me a **generic solution**?

Thanks for help so far :)

Comment: @dfhwze Can you also consider the above scenario and provide an answer

Comment: @pradeep I edited my answer to support multiple "enums"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you know `EHgFileTag`'s names are compatible with `EFileTag`, which is what the title suggests.

```
var ft = EFileTag.Clean;
var hgft = (char)(EHgFileTag)Enum.Parse(typeof(EHgFileTag), ft.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is obvious for getting Enum value with another Enum's named constants. But you could still enhance it with the following.

**Getting converted value:**

```
try {
  var d = Enum.Parse (GetRepoType (), nameof (EFileTag.Clean));
  Console.WriteLine ($"USAGE: {d} - {Convert.ToChar (d)} - {(int)d}");
} catch (Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine (e);
}
```

**Method for getting appropriate type for conversion:**

```
static Type GetRepoType () {
  // [typeName - set the typeName with args (or) config settings]
  switch (typeName) { 
    case "hg": return typeof (EHgFileTag);
    case "git": return typeof (EGitFileTag);
    // Extend cases for other repositories.........
    default: return typeof (EHgFileTag);
  }
}
```